# Highcharts add a serie that does not exist

Tags: highcharts

Here its my example:

http://jsfiddle.net/mvPFG/140/

And html source code from series is:

```
 series: [{name:'Test',data: (function() {var data = [];data.push([1455073200000,1]);return data;})()},{
```

Any idea why i get "Series 2:0" ?

Regards!

Comment: Why do you have a second series in series array? **jlbriggs** answers your question, but if you want to keep second empty series and hide it in legend then you could set `showInLegend: false` for that series. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tdjg977x/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting a second series, because you have specified a second series in your options (so, even though it is empty, yes - it does exist):

```
series: [{
    name:'Test',
  data: (function() {
    var data = [];
    data.push([1455073200000,1]);
    return data;
   })()
},{            
        // <--- this is an empty series, and it is showing in your legend,
        // <--- and taking up space in your chart
}]
```

Removing the empty series removes it from your legend and chart:

- http://jsfiddle.net/mvPFG/141/